# Need Help in Xamarin UI Test Automation

Tags: xamarin

I am currently working on Mobile App automation .Have come across Xamarin UI Test Automation.But I could find less documentation on that.
I have downloaded xamarin studio on Mac as well as on Windows.

But I need help on scripting from scratch.How can I use the tool to script and run on Android as well IOS phones.

Comment: Start with https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/

Comment: https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/05/08/enterprise-ready-testing-in-xamarin/ This blog has test application, that you can download and start using

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. This two links: [bdd](http://arteksoftware.com/bdd-tests-with-xamarin-uitest-and-specflow/), [ui test](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/uitest-and-test-cloud/) helped me. First link is about BDD testing but include what you need.

Also you should check **Xamarin UI tests recorder** that can simplify your task but it's not a free.